# Get absolute time using result of System.currentTimeMillis in android

Tags: java, android

I defined BuildConfig field to use as app version.

```
buildConfigField "long", "BUILDTIME", System.currentTimeMillis() + "L"
```

And I can get that value properly in my MainActivity.

```kotlin
binding.buttonTest.text = "Build Version is: " + SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss", Locale.KOREA)
                               .format(BuildConfig.BUILDTIME)
```

But when testing my app on test phone and AVD which has different time zone,
the string that SimpleDateFormat returns are not same.

-- RESULT --
Test phone: Build Version is: 20220502172527
AVD: Build Version is: 20220502082738

I think it's because SimpleDateFormat gives relative time, not absolute time.
How can I get absolute time in android with result of System.currentTimeMillis()?
Thanks.

Note: I don't want to use Date(), because all of it's get methods are deprecated.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`. That class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Instead use classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

You seem to not care about fractional second, so use a count of whole seconds since the epoch reference of 1970-01-01T00:00Z.

```
Instant
.now()
.getEpochSecond()
```

Generate text.

```
Instant
.ofEpochSecond(
    mySavedCountOfSecondsFromEpoch
)  // Returns an `Instant`.
.atOffset( 
    ZoneOffset.UTC 
) // Returns an `OffsetDateTime`.
.format(
    DateTimeFormatter
    .ofPattern( "uuuuMMddHHmmss" )
)  // Returns a `String`.
```

> 20220501123456

## Avoid legacy classes

You are using terrible date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes.

Android 26+ includes an implementation. For earlier Android, the latest tooling brings most of the functionality via “API desugaring”.

## `Instant`

The call to `System.currentTimeMillis()` can be replaced with `Instant.now().toEpochMilli()`.

Parse the count of milliseconds since the epoch reference of first moment of 1970 as seen in UTC.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( myMillis ) ;
```

## `OffsetDateTime`

For more flexible generating of text, convert from the basic building-block `Instant` class to `OffsetDateTime`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

## `DateTimeFormatter`

Define a formatting pattern.

Be aware that your desired format involves data loss, by lopping off the fractional second.

No need for the locale you passed. In your desired format nothing needs localization.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuuMMddHHmmss" ) ;
```

Generate text.

```
String output = odt.format( f ) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the `TimeZone` your `SimpleDateFormat` object uses with `setTimeZone(TimeZone.UTC)`.

Comment: Replaced private constant `TimeZone.UTC` into `TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+09:00")` and it works fine. Thanks for your help.